# Text in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, textures

Is there a primitive or option that prevents `Text[]` from turning to face the camera in `Graphics3D`? If I use `Text[]` as it is right now, it acts like a sprite and always faces the camera (under rotation).

I've been able to semi-achieve what I was looking for by using `Text[]` as a texture for a flat `Cuboid[]` and `Polygon[]` but this seems overly complicated for what should be simple.

Comment: Text wrapped at `Text` expression is inherently 2D even when it is inserted into a 3D graphic. There is no built-in implementation of true 3D text so far.

Comment: Is there a way to use the way `Arrow[]` is wrapped for 3D graphics and apply it to `Text[]`?